How to deserialize ata of spl token 2022?
I found the length of spl token 2022 ata is not 165, so I can't unpack the account.


The data length of EeF6oBy6AQiBJoRx5xiRNxa6cmpQE3ayVagj28QFZuyg is 183. So, how to deserialize it?

let ata0 =
spl_token_2022::extension::StateWithExtensions::<spl_token_2022::state::Account>::unpack(
&ata0_data,
)
.unwrap();
